# `Date.strptime` unexpected behaviour

Tags: ruby

I try to parse string `"01.09 2015"` with `"%d.%m %y"`, but it returns year `2020`.

```
require 'date'

year = Time.now.year.to_s # => "2015"
ny = (Time.now.year+1).to_s # => "2016"
sem = "01.09"
Date.strptime(sem+" "+year, "%d.%m %y")
# => #<Date: 2020-09-01 ((2459094j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

I don't get what's happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `%y` (meaning `year % 100 (00..99)`) with `%Y` (*4 digits year*):

```
Date.strptime("01.09 2015", "%d.%m %Y")
```